# SQL Server not allowing NULL for Date even though mentioned as null while creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, nullable

I am trying to create a table for library management system and i want my date_in to be null for some cases. When I am trying to give null it is giving me error as:

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 8, column 7 (date_in).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 9, column 7 (date_in).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 10, column 7 (date_in).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 11, column 7 (date_in).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 12, column 7 (date_in).
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 13, column 7 (date_in).

I have explicitly mentioned that attribute to take null but still it is not allowing.
help me

thanks in advance

Here is the query:

```
create table book_loans
(
     loan_id varchar(10) not null,
     book_id varchar(10) not null,
     branch_id smallint not null,
     card_no varchar(10) not null,
     date_out date null default null,
     due_date date null default null,
     date_in date null default null
)

BULK
INSERT book_loans
FROM 'F:\sql project\resources\SQL_library_project_data\book_loans_data.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '<>',
FIRSTROW=2
)
GO
```

here is the data file:

```
load_id,book_id,branch_id,card_no,date_out,due_date,date_in<>
1,0399147020,1,9019,2013-11-22,2013-12-06,2013-12-01<>
2,0030059380,4,9007,2013-12-01,2013-12-15,2013-12-16<>
3,0671880756,5,9018,2013-12-08,2013-12-22,2013-12-22<>
4,0911625291,3,9013,2014-01-02,2014-01-16,2014-01-12<>
5,0688161995,5,9022,2014-02-10,2014-02-24,2014-03-01<>
6,0911625291,2,9011,2014-03-03,2014-03-17,2014-03-16<>
7,1861003730,3,9034,2014-04-17,2014-05-01,NULL<>
8,0201612585,3,9034,2014-04-17,2014-05-01,NULL<>
9,1565927699,3,9034,2014-04-17,2014-05-01,NULL<>
10,0192860925,4,9009,2014-04-18,2014-05-02,NULL<>
11,0805057579,1,9021,2014-04-18,2014-05-02,NULL<>
12,0911625607,2,9018,2014-04-19,2014-05-03,NULL
```

Comment: I think it's trying to convert 'NULL' to datetime, instead of reading it as NULL, just a guess.

Comment: well the above dates are not making a problem. so looks like date format will not make a difference. only the ones having null are making the issue.

Comment: Can you try with 'NULL' s removed from the file? i.e. `11,0805057579,1,9021,2014-04-18,2014-05-02,<>`

Comment: got it. i think it is interpreting null as a string. what @artm said worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way BULK INSERT works is that a NULL value needs to be an empty field, i.e. `value,2,,3`. Two delimeters without a value in between declares null value. In your file, you're using NULL to indicate DB NULL value but there's no way for bulk insert to read that as a DB NULL value because you could be trying to insert string 'NULL' in to the field. You can either remove all `NULL` s from your text file, or if that's not the option you can bulk import to a temp table where the last column is defined as varchar and after the import if the value of last column is 'NULL' then use a DB null value.

Also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms162802.aspx if you want to produce a text file from sql DB.

Answer (score 1):

```
BULK
INSERT book_loans
FROM 'F:\sql project\resources\SQL_library_project_data\book_loans_data.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '<>',
FIRSTROW=2,
KEEPNULLS
)
```

Comment: not working. keepnulls is not making the difference. same errors persist.

Comment: thing is. it is taking NULL as a string and comparing to a date type which is an error. so what worked for me is giving on value in that spot.

Comment: KEEPNULLS is used when there's a nullable column in the table with a default value, if the value in file is null and this option is on, then the column is stored as NULL, if the value in file is null and this option is off, columns takes its default value.